# No results in query after loading data into AWS RDS using Data Pipeline?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I have loaded some csv data from S3 into RDS using Data Pipeline. I am using Postgres 10.6. I know the Data Pipeline is definitely doing some writes, since I can see the corresponding increases in write latency, write IOPS, queue depth, etc. The problem is I don't know what it is writing to, because running `select count(*) from users` returns 0. There are no errors or warnings in Data Pipeline.

I am running the query using `psycopg2`:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host=host,
    port=5432,
    user=username,
    password=password,
    connect_timeout=10,
    database='postgres'
)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select count(*) from users')
```

This is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, gender, country_code)
VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET
gender = EXCLUDED.gender, country_code = EXCLUDED.country_code;
```

This is the config for my RDS database/data node:

```
{
  "*password": "#{*myRDSPassword}",
  "name": "postgres",
  "jdbcProperties": "allowMultiQueries=true",
  "id": "rds_mysql",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "type": "RdsDatabase",
  "rdsInstanceId": "#{myRDSInstanceId}",
  "username": "#{myRDSUsername}"
},
{
  "database": {
    "ref": "rds_mysql"
  },
  "name": "DestinationRDSTable",
  "insertQuery": "#{myRDSTableInsertSql}",
  "id": "DestinationRDSTable",
  "type": "SqlDataNode",
  "table": "#{myRDSTableName}",
  "selectQuery": "select * from #{table}"
},
{
  "myRDSTableName": "users",
}
```

The only explanation I can think of is that I am writing to a different database than the default of `postgres` which I am querying from, but I am not sure where I should set this property. Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, fixed this issue by adding optional parameter `databaseName="postgres"` to the RdsDatabase object.